# nested loop and newaxis numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say, I have a empty list labelled Energies and I'd fill this list by looping over some others variables as below,

```py
r=read('atoms_positions.txt')
e=read('previous_calculations.txt')
Energies=np.zeros([len(e), len(r)])
spd=3
for a in range(len(r)):
    for b in range(spd):
        Energies[:,a]+=dos_site(a,spd)
```

My first question is : How do the 'Energies[:,a]' will look like? I mean how do the loop will execute ? What's the shape and dimension of Energies after running the code .

My second question is about the newaxis numpy function, let's say I have an array 1_D like this ''density''  and then I wanna do the following operation:

```py
density=np.array([list of random numbers])

gauss=np.array([list of random numbers])

density+=density[:,np.newaxis]*gauss
```

Again I cannot understand the output of my array after running the above piece of code ???
'''
Please note that dos_site is a function that return an 1_D array.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: `Energies=np.zeros([len(e), len(r)])` creates a numpy array with a fixed size and float dtype.  The assignments in the loop (including the `+=` don't change its size or dtype.  `Energies` is **not** an empty list, and `+=` is not a list append.  Don't try to adapted working list code to work with arrays; there are too many differences.

Comment: Start an interactive python session, import numpy, and experiment with some small arrays.  Good SO numpy answers demonstrate this kind of testing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Energies[:,a]+=dos_site(a,spd)
```

This adds (then assigns) the one-d array (returned by `dos_site`) to the *a'th* column

```
>>> a = np.zeros([5, 6])
>>> a[:,0] += np.arange(5)
>>> a
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
>>> a[:,0] += np.arange(5)
>>> a
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [6., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [8., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
>>> a[:,1] += np.arange(5)
>>> a
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [2., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [4., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [6., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [8., 4., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

---

Using `np.newaxis` allows [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> y = np.array([3,1,6,2])

>>> x[:,np.newaxis]*y
array([[ 3,  1,  6,  2],
       [ 6,  2, 12,  4],
       [ 9,  3, 18,  6],
       [12,  4, 24,  8]])
```

In this example `np.newaxis` adds another dimension resulting in a shape of (4,1)

```
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> x[:,np.newaxis]
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

The array `y` is multiplied to each item in `x`, creating a two-d array.

```
[[1 * y],
 [2 * y],
 [3 * y],
 [4 * y]]
```

---

[Array Broadcasting in Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy)